# Add scrollbar without shrinking div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have following HTML

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="subdiv"> <span>
            Some Text
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#main {
    height: 300px;
    border:2px solid green;
    width:100%;
   overflow:auto;
}
#subdiv {
    width:90%;
    height:90%;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Now when the browser window size is reduced i want the `subdiv to remain always it's original size i.e 90%` and just add scrollbar to main div, but no matter what i try the `subdiv is also getting reduced`.

Like in this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3cq4582L/), want the div having red margin to remain constant and add scroll bar to div having green border.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I don't think it is duplicate, these 2 question are totally different

Comment: Hey by any chance, have you fixed it? Because I am having the same error also

Answer (score -1):

Remove the Width and height from the subdiv.

Comment: Not working. I have attached sample fiddle,please do check it :)

Comment: Ohi sorry just delete the height of the sub div it will work...

Comment: Not working. Did you get my question. The subdiv should always be as it is inital size

Comment: You mean to say you want give scrollbar to outer div instead of the window...please give me some example so that i can help you..

Comment: Yes right .Outer div gets scrollbar and innerdiv remains unchanged:)

Comment: Use the following link add the jquery http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/complete_examples.html

Comment: You have not understood my question dear